# How to rename a file in Windows 7 using the keyboard?

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts

When I try to rename a file in Windows 7 by pressing <kbd>F2</kbd>, I get the "search" window. If I press <kbd>F3</kbd>, still I get the search window...

What is the keyboard shortcut to rename a file in Windows 7?

Comment: a reboot fixed the problem, strange
have you have experienced this in the RC1?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

It should be <kbd>F2</kbd>. Make sure you have a file selected. I've noticed that in Windows7 it's a little more tricky to select a file and easier to miss if a file isn't selected.

Answer (score 8):

Are you by chance using a Microsoft keyboard with the specialized function keys? There may be a key to the right of the "F" row that looks like <kbd>F</kbd>.

You're right, rename is F2. If the function mode is on, though, the keyboard could be sending a different command.